# Как перевести handle?

Tags: переводы

Handle - в программистском смысле (напр. file handle). 
Это не дескриптор, не ключ, не указатель, не символ ....

"Токен" - похоже, и звучит по-русски приятно - но нельзя же переводить иностранное слово другим иностранным словом.

Comment: К тому же token и handle - разные вещи, которые вполне могут встретиться в тексте по соседству друг с другом. Token это (примерно) значок, он может быть и для пришпиливания к чему-то, и сам по себе. А handle именно только для приделывания.

Comment: Кстати, про token в таком значении вообще не слышал. Для меня токен - это некая "штучная" единица информации, програмного кода и т. п. Не то чтобы совсем атомарная, но воспринимаемая как целое. Не знаю, может, я давно устарел.

Comment: @behemothus Вот хотя бы в [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token) упоминается среди прочих в значении опознавательного знака, в том числе и в программировании

Comment: Что-то не вижу такого. 0_o

Comment: А какой английский текст вы соотносите с опознавательным знаком?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @behemothus Вот - Session token: a unique identifier of an interaction session. Security token or hardware token, authentication token or cryptographic token: a physical device for computer authentication. Access token: a system object representing the subject of access control operations. Invitation token, in an invitation system. - это всё пометки, нужные для распознавания авторизованных субъектов

Comment: А, вы  identifier трактуете как "опознавательный знак"? Ну может быть, ладно, спасибо. Просто для меня "идентификатор", "опознавательный знак" и "значок" (как у вас было) - это вещи разные, хотя в чем-то и сходные. На  "token=идетификатор"  (в соответствующем контексте) в принципе согласен. Но handle - это все-таки нечто другое. Ладно, вроде разобрались, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Handle - в программистском смысле (напр. file handle). Это не дескриптор, не ключ, не указатель, не символ

Это именно дескриптор. Но "дескриптор" некоторые тоже хотят перевести, и сделать это легко – "описатель". Однако программисты обычно говорят просто хэндл. Неверный хэндл, где у тебя хэндл этого файла и т.д.

File handle возвращает функция, открывающая или создающая файл.

А вот "ручка" совсем не подходит, и так не говорят.

Comment: Дескиптор - это дескриптор. Описание. А handle - прибор, устройство (софтовые),  средство доступа Иногда это взаимозаменяемые понятия, но редко.

Comment: Семантически ближе всего указатель или токен, но эти слова уже заняты. Буквально это то за что держат некий предмет, например ручка от сковородки, поводок от собаки, ухватка, прихватка (брррр....)

Comment: Дескриптор, в смысле файла - это другая, вполне определённая вещь. Это struct FILE.  Pardon my Dutch.

Comment: Я, может, и согласен, что совсем не подходит, но что так наверняка говорят программисты - это видно хотя бы по ссылке из моего ответа.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე - что говорят - да, но вот делать выводы из столь малорепрезентативного и неавторитетного источника не стоит.

Answer (score 5):

handle — *маркер* или *дескриптор*, в зависимости от контекста.
В частности, file handle — *дескриптор файла*.
Шаблон ООП — *описатель*.

token — *лексема* (в синтаксическом анализе). В остальных контекстах *маркер* или *токен*.

Взято большей частью [отсюда](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx).

Comment: Правильно. Но есть контекст, когда нужно как-то передать смысл "ручка", "привод", как и говорит автор с грузинским ником.  Собственно, я только над эти смыслом и думаю... Остальное все не слишком актуально. Ну зачем еще и file handle переводить через дескриптор, когда есть вполне самодостаточное file descriptor.

Comment: @behemothus Ну да. И привод лучше ручки - и по смыслу, и по уклюжести. А может есть что-нибудь ещё более подходящее в этом направлении, не знаю.

Comment: Да может и есть, но если не вошло в лексикон программистов, большого смысла сейчас искать уже нету.

Comment: Спасибо, как то я забыл про слона-то :) Но у них нет адекватного перевода.

Comment: *...как и говорит автор с грузинским ником.* Да не с ником, а с именем (и фамилией). :))

Answer (score 2):

Судя по этому вопросу: [Что такое "ручки" на сленге программистов? | Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431135), программисты на своём жаргоне пользуются буквальным переводом "ручка", в значении "синтаксическое приспособление для работы с объектом". Например, имеется файл, который надо открыть; для этого его надо как-то обозначить; file handle в этом случае это действительно что-то вроде ручки, которую к файлу приделывают, чтоб было за что взяться. Так что по смыслу это действительно дескриптор, а так в принципе "ручка" думаю приемлемый термин. Во всяком случае, неизвестно, чем "дескриптор" лучше чем, скажем, какой-нибудь "хэндл".

Comment: Согласен с вами, Мамука, дескриптор не годится. Пусть уж будет хэндл, если так действительно говорят.

Comment: Ручка - буквальный перевод, но по русски ручка это то чем пишут. Занято.

Comment: @ddbug ну это ещё надо выяснить, которая ручка более занята - которой пишут или которая от чайника :D

Comment: Хорошее примечание. Чайник в наше время крепче ассоциируется с программистом чем ручка которой пишут. (гм. тогда ручку от чайника можно перевести обратно как n00b handle)